# Probability of stopping a production line even when the failed ratio is not more than 6 percent

Tags: probability

Imagine a company has someone who controls the production line and every time he does that, he choses 15 products and makes sure that no more than 1 product has failed according to the rules.  If more than 1 product is not good, then he stops the production line.The target is to make sure that the ratio of failed products are not more than 6 percent of all.

But Sometimes, even when the ratio of failed products in all of the products are not more than 6 percent, he finds more than 1 failed product in the 15 products he randomely chose.

Find the fraction of time that this thing happens.

Note:  The problem here is that i don't know the relation between time and the event.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked for Binomial distribution?

Comment: @BGM i don't know what it is ...

Comment: Maybe I explain the term "fraction of time" a little bit first. Imagine you can repeat the experiment for an infinite amount of times, independently and identically. Hence the experiment can be consider as a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli trials, with success or failures as the only possible outcomes. The fraction, or the sample mean (average) time of happening will converge to the true mean by LLN. And we know that the mean of a Bernoulli random variable will be equal to the probability of a trial having success. So your question is equivalent to the probability of that happening.

Comment: @BGM Thank you sir :) can u please write an answer so that i could accept ? ( with more details )

Comment: @BGM what is i.i.d and LLN?

Comment: i.i.d: independent identically distributed;   LLN:  Law of Large Numbers

Comment: @GabrielBurns thank you sir :) i don't know why no one wants to write an answer instead of commenting :))